# Using a Cron Job to check if my mod_wsgi / apache server is running and restart

Tags: linux, django, apache, cron, mod-wsgi

my group and I are running a server that is based upon Django and uses mod_wsgi to run an Apache server. We will not be working on this project after it is over, so I am attempting to set up cronjob similar functionality to check if the apache server has shut down(system restart or power failure), and if it has, will restart the server for me. I've found documentation on how to check if an apache server is down and restart the server if it is, but our server uses https and thus our start command is pretty verbose.

Can I simply use the functionality provided in these examples:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/277389/cron-job-to-restart-apache

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-a-simple-bash-script-to-restart-server-programs

Or do I need a much more complicated process to make this happen?

The command we use to initially start the server is

python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --https-port 8000 --ssl-certificate (certificate Location) --server-name (Domain Name)

I'm pretty new to Linux and using both Mod-wsgi as well as Apache so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using the `--setup-only` option to mod_wsgi-express or the Django integration for it, to generate the configuration but not run it. Then as others have mentioned, integrate it into the system service manager.

The two commands for starting and stopping the Apache/mod_wsgi instance would be `apachectl start` and `apachectl stop`, where `apachectl` is that which was generated when running with the additional `--setup-only` option.

When running it as a system service, also make sure you use the `--server-root` option to specify a more persistent location for the generated configuration. Do not use the default under `/tmp` if running for anything but temporary development sessions as some Linux systems will remove files under `/tmp` causing things to start failing after a while.

Also, since under a service manager it would generally be starting as root, particularly if listening on port 80 is a requirement, ensure you use the `--user` and `--group` options to specify what user/group your Python web application should run as.

Read:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

for more details of the `--setup-only` option and `start-server` commands for generating the configuration. Because you are using the Django integration, you will need to use the `--setup-only` option.

For more informed helped, bring your issue to the mod_wsgi mailing list. The mod_wsgi-express way of running Apache/mod_wsgi is new enough that unlikely that anyone here is really going to know much about it.

Comment: So would I simply us the same command but with the setup only command in it? I am also a bit confused as to how I integrate this into a system service manager. I went to the link that you provided but I don't understand what the next step would be after I run the setup-only command.

Comment: As StackOverflow is not a discussion forum, I would suggest you ask your question on the mod_wsgi mailing list. Otherwise you will need to wait until I get to doing a blog post about integration of mod_wsgi-express into system startup scripts. That will likely happen in next few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is not good way to resolve this problem.

I recommend you use monit (https://mmonit.com/). It is cool program for checking services.

```
apt-get install monit
```

Apache restart configuration directives:

```
check process httpd with pidfile /var/run/httpd.pid
  group apache
  start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/httpd stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80
  protocol http then restart
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this at all. There is no reason to start up Apache manually; once it's installed as a system service, Ubuntu will start it up automatically on restart or crash.

You should reflect on why you feel the need to do this for Apache specifically, and not any of the other system services you depend on, such as the database.